# python. Исходные данные после preprocessing.scale

Tags: python, препроцессор, scipy, sklearn

Возможно, глупый вопрос. Но вот ситуация:

В функцию приходят данные X = даты в timestamp, Y = значения соответствующие данной дате. Я хочу построить приближенную кривую по этим данным. Мне естественно придется использовать preprocessing.scale для X и все будет хорошо. (для построения кривой, я использую curve_fit)

НО: вот у меня есть кривая, есть параметры ее. А что если я хочу узнать значение этой кривой по какой-то другой дате в будущем. Кривая же не примет timestamp в аргумент, а нормировать его в отрыве от других данных - невозможно.

Что делать, если я захочу узнать, когда эта кривая достигнет какого-то значения - например, 1. Как узнать, в какой timestamp это произойдет?

Answer (score 0):

Для того, что бы узнать "значение .... по какой-то другой дате в будущем" вам не кривульки надо рисовать, а модель строить. Регрессионную, сглаживания, Хольта-Винтерса, SARIMA, LSTM и так далее. Вот они как раз дают ответ на вопрос "каково предположительно будет значение нашей переменной Y в день Х". И не просто ответ, но часто еще и его доверительный интервал.
Всем эти занимается теория временнЫх рядов. Ну, и немного -  Deep Learning.